# Работаю с Vue и не совсем понимаю, куда расположить свой код?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Я делаю запрос к API, после чего кладу данные в Vuex, далее беру их в компоненте, который отвечает за графики.
Он принимает данные вида:

```
[
  {
    x: 1,
    y: 2
  },
  {
    x: 2,
    y: 4
  }
]
```

Но с API мне возвращается только два списка - с X и Y.

У меня есть код, который перебирает эти списки и создаёт из них объекты.

```
key = fullDataList[5]["chart"]["y_struct"]
value = fullDataList[5]["chart"]["x"],
result = {},
key.forEach((key,i) => result[key] = value[i]);
```

Подскажите, куда мне будет лучше его вставить? После данного действия, мне надо передать в  компонент, переменную result
Данный график появляется, только после получения данных.
Пытался в mounted, но не сильно получилось.

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если правильно понял, то вам скорее будет лучше брать данные так

```
computed: {
    ...mapState(["yourState" ...anotherStates]),
    data() {
        return this.yourState.someDataFromVuexState;
    },
}
```

а в секции template просто обращаться как к "data"